# Reading Data from a document after checking if its subcollection's document is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

[image]

as you can see in the images provided, I have structured my database as follows.

```
Group => contains all groups
Test A => one of the groups
Sessions => contains all the sessions dates and timings of that particular group
date => document is titled by the date of that session
```

I am trying to read the group document that has a session today. Is this possible? even if it is a multistep process how can I do that?
to simplify, I'm trying to read the group document where a document titled with today's date in its subcollection "Sessions" exists. If no such document exists then it can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can't be done in a single query.

Bu you can:

1. Build a DocumentReference to the sessions document using the group name and the formatted date.
2. get() the document. If it exists:

   1. Build another DocumentReference to the group document
   2. Read it